# MAPBOX how to draw multiples lines and change color

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I will like to use MapBox maps (javascript API) to draw a route on a map with multiples colours, 
each color will mean a different transportation mode, for example:
1) bus
2) car
3) train

I found this code as example:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-draw/

Hope someone can give advice.

Thanks J.Rico

Comment: Built on top of Leaflet - here's a link to the Leaflet JS API - http://leafletjs.com/reference.html - read up and good luck.

Comment: you might take a look at the [leaflet geojson](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) example too

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using **Polyline** functionality from mapbox api, you need to provide a set of points **(latitude,longitude)** that constitute your route, here is some snippet of code that may help you from mapbox, you can [see reference](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/polyline/) in **mapbox** api website

1. Points array for the route

   ```
   // Create array of lat,lon points
   var line_points = [
      [38.893596444352134, -77.0381498336792],
      [38.89337933372204, -77.03792452812195],
      [38.89316222242831, -77.03761339187622],
      [38.893028615148424, -77.03731298446655],
      [38.892920059048464, -77.03691601753235],
      [38.892903358095296, -77.03637957572937],
      [38.89301191422077, -77.03592896461487],
      [38.89316222242831, -77.03549981117249],
      [38.89340438498248, -77.03514575958252],
      [38.893596444352134, -77.0349633693695]
   ];
   ```
2. Choose the color you want

   ```
   // Define polyline options
   // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline
   var polyline_options = {
      color: '#000'
   };
   ```
3. Draw the route

   ```
   // Defining a polygon here instead of a polyline will connect the
   // endpoints and fill the path.
   // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon
   var polyline = L.polyline(line_points, polyline_options).addTo(map);
   ```

Good luck.